# Increment in array access

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Why can't I increment an index when accessing an array? The code works like it's a post-increment.

```
for (uint256 i = remove_idx; i < length;) {
      validators[i] = validators[++i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get enough context from your code, but I created the following code as an example of what's going on (read the comments):

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    uint256[] public validators;

    constructor() {
        validators.push(1);
        validators.push(2);
        validators.push(3);
        validators.push(4);
        validators.push(5);
        validators.push(6);
    }

    function getValidators() public view returns(uint256[] memory) {
        return validators;
    }

    function etc() public {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < validators.length - 1;) {

            // validators after this will be [1,2,3,4,5,6].
            // i is incremented first, if it was 0, now is 1.
            // Then, validators[i] is actually validators[1] = 2, which is the value
            // copied, meaning, we are assigning the value value that was originally there starting from index 1.
           // validators[i] = validators[++i];

            // One option is to copy the value of i before incrementing it and using it to assign the value.
            // validators after this will be [2,3,4,5,6,6], so we need pop the last one too
            uint256 j = i;
            validators[j] = validators[++i];
            validators.pop();

            // validators after this will be [2,3,4,5,6,6]. At the end we will have 2 numbers the same.
            // That's because we are assigning the next one to the previous one, but there's no next one at the end,
            // it would be out of bounds and it would revert.
            // To solve this, we would need to `.pop` the last one.
            //validators[i - 1] = validators[++i];
            //validators.pop();

            // validators will be [1,1,1,1,1] after this because it copys the value of validators[0] first, which is 1,
            // then increment i to 1, then validators[1] = 1, and it keeps doing the same, so, all of them will be 1.
            //validators[i] = validators[i++];
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, you are incrementing `i` on the right side of the expression. The right side is evaluated first, so when the left side is going to be evaluated, `i` is already incremented. Which is not what you want, I guess.

To solve this, you have a couple of options.

1. Copy `i` before it's incremented

```js
uint256 j = i;
validators[j] = validators[++i];
validators.pop();
```

2. Extract 1 from `i` in the left side of the evaluation:

```js
validators[i - 1] = validators[++i];
validators.pop();
```